# Can you decode the response of a SC query in C#?

Tags: multiversx

Is there a known way to decode the response from a SC Query into a readable object in C# ?

If my contract returns a custom structure which has the TypeAbi decorator, is there a way to read that data in C# or is there another way to decode it except using the abi.json file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the structure of the struct to decode the response.

Of course you can hardcode it instead of using abi files, but I would say it would be better to make it generic from the beginning.

You can take a look at the [erdjs implementation](https://github.com/ElrondNetwork/elrond-sdk-erdjs/tree/main/src/smartcontracts/codec) to see how values are encoded/decoded.

Or you take a look at the [serialization docs](https://docs.elrond.com/developers/developer-reference/elrond-serialization-format/).

Comment: So basically, I'd have to create my own Deserializer, first translating all the erdjs classes to C#, then using them in the structure I want to decode.

Am I getting this right?

Comment: Yes, basically :)